# Calling class via string classname

Tags: php, silex

I seem to be stuck on a very basic PHP issue.

```
        $test = new TestClass;
```

Works and creates an object of TestClass.

```
        $class = 'TestClass';
        $test = new $class;
```

Fails with the error Uncaught Error: Class 'TestClass' not found.

Why is this failing? I used this a lot in the passed and then it always worked. Could it be because of the Namespaces? How do I need to load it then?

All these classes are in the same namespace and are being called from the same namespace

Comment: The file that contains `TestClass` is either not loaded or TestClass is in (another) namespace. Can you show us the declaration of TestClass (including any namespace)?

Comment: This SSCCE demonstrates the technique you are trying works fine: https://gist.github.com/adamcameron/7066c28c38d15219a9ed9554ec8d786c (but confirm it runs for you too). So I think you need to expand on your situation and provide more info. Come up with a version of this SSCCE which demonstrates your issue, and update your question accordingly. In the process, yer likely to work out what yer doing wrong, too ;-)